# Add geometry line to the map

Tags: geometry, java, geotools

I'm trying to test the code example on the page http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/tutorial/geometry/geometrycrs.html
I copied this example into eclipse

```
 Transaction transaction = new DefaultTransaction("Reproject");
    try (FeatureWriter<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> writer =
                    dataStore.getFeatureWriterAppend(createdName, transaction);
            SimpleFeatureIterator iterator = featureCollection.features()) {
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            // copy the contents of each feature and transform the geometry
            SimpleFeature feature = iterator.next();
            SimpleFeature copy = writer.next();
            copy.setAttributes(feature.getAttributes());

            Geometry geometry = (Geometry) feature.getDefaultGeometry();
            Geometry geometry2 = JTS.transform(geometry, transform);

            copy.setDefaultGeometry(geometry2);
            writer.write();
        }
        transaction.commit();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Export to shapefile complete");
    } catch (Exception problem) {
        problem.printStackTrace();
        transaction.rollback();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Export to shapefile failed");
    } finally {
        transaction.close();
    }
}
```

But I got some error with transform function. Eclipse "ask" to change Geometry type to Envelope. But when I changed it didn't solve this problem . Eclipse asked to change envelope to geometry again. How can I fix this error?

Comment: please don't post pictures of code. What is the error message?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any errors in the [code](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/docs/src/main/java/org/geotools/tutorial/crs/CRSLab.java) when I plug it into my eclipse. The most likely issue is that you have imported the "wrong" `geometry` class. Make sure it is a JTS geometry - `import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry;` or `import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;` depending on the [version of GeoTools](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/welcome/upgrade.html) you are using.